# Visual-Studio fails at start-up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In the last few days, every time I open VS (2010) it crashes right after start-up:
[image]
As weird as it is, when I'm debugging VS with a new instance of vs, it does not crash, and I'm able to close the solution and work properly.

Also when I start VS with a solution (with Win7's jump lists or using CMD arguments),
I get an "explorer crashed and will restart" message that instantly disappears.
After it, visual studio starts normally.
My system:

- win7 32bit
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional (using productivity power tools

How can I solve this problem or at least figure out how to investgate it?

Comment: @Gator Thank you once again for your useful advice

Comment: Have you tried Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs -> Visual Studio -> Change/Repair?

Comment: Also try clearing out the Visual Studio settings under Documents and Settings. I've had issues with that in the past. My folder location is C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\ and I often rename the folder, just in case ;-)

Comment: I changed the name of the directory. VS gently informs me of the missing files and crashes :(

Comment: That's weird. I just renamed mine and VS2010 didn't bat an eyelid... it complained then recreated the folder structure and started up. Guess it's time for an uninstall/reinstall as Jared advises.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [resetting all the VS settings](http://www.platinumbay.com/blogs/dotneticated/archive/2007/09/02/reset-the-visual-studio-environment.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Visual Studio is in a bad state.  The most likely causes of this are

- A misbehaving extension
- The install is corrupted in some way

To rule out the misbehaving extensions run devenv.exe with the /SafeMode option.  If this works then I'd start uninstalling extensions till you find the guilty party.

If it still crashes with /SafeMode then I'd repair the install through "Add / Remove Programs"

Comment: It didn't crash with safemode, but when I uninstalled all plugins and even repaired it through add\remove programs nothing was changed.
What else safemode affects except the extensions?

Comment: @GiladNaaman the documentation is vague and says "default environment." Not exactly sure what that means.  My next step would be to reset settings with /ResetSettings

Comment: I did :( twice. I guess last resort is Microsoft Support

Comment: @GiladNaaman sadly it might be :(. I've rarely found a problem that can't be fixed by the steps I listed. When it coudln't it was because I'd hand patched VS with a bad DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to do a complete re-install after uninstalling VS 2010. This could be because some libraries could be missing or there's some conflict.